# How to spy on nested method in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Consider this usual situation:

```
var a = {
  b: {
    c: function() {}
  }
}
```

I want to spy on c and though it's easy with:

```
spyOn(a.b, 'c');
```

However it creates a spy but it doesn't work. No errors or so are shown and I can see there's a spy when debugging.

How can I spy on a nested method?

**UPDATE**

Output is: `Object [object Object] has no method 'tohaveBeenCalledWith'`

Comment: Can explain what does not work, cause this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle when I do except(a.b.c).haveBeenCalled() I get Object [object Object] has no method 'tohaveBeenCalled'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess typo is the problem; spying on nested functions works well as you outlined.

Be carefull with the casing: Jasmine function is `toHaveBeenCalled()`. Since you wrote `tohaveBeenCalled()` the error message makes sense (because there is no such method). JavaScript is case-sensitive :-)